High School Math Combinatorics Problem: Rearranging letters of a string
I stumbled upon this question yesterday which asked:

How many ways can you rewrite the word PIGGYBANK such that no letter is in its original place?

This was the last problem on my PreCalc test about Combanitorics that I couldn't get. I said the answer was $${7 \choose 2 }\times5!\times2,$$ because $7 \choose 2$ represents the number of ways to choose $2$ positions out of $7$ available positions for the G's. $5!$ represents the number of ways to arrange the remaining $5$ letters whose spots haven't been taken by the G's once the G's have been chosen. This is because there are $5$ letters left to arrange. The $2$ at the end represents the ways you can put the two remaining letters.
Can someone tell me if the answer is right or not and how to get the correct answer?

You want us to verify chatGPT?  What have you tried?

Would you know how to do it if there were no repeated G in the word? Example: PIGZYBANK.

Try with APPLE so that you can check your work by brute force.

Ok I'll try that, but can someone provide an answer to my question?

You are right that there are $\binom72$ ways to choose the positions for Gs. They took spaces of some other two letters. These two letters won’t take their places in permutation, they are safe. What happens to the $9-2=7$ non-G letters? We should arrange them in such way that $9-2-2=5$ letters change their places. Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to calculate this number.
There are $7!$ permutations of these letters. Suppose one of the letters in danger preserved its place. There are $\binom51$ ways to choose this letter and $6!$ ways to arrange the other letters.
Now suppose two letters in danger preserve their places. We should add these combinations since we subtracted them twice in the previous calculation. There are $\binom52\times 5!$ of them.
And so on. In accordance to the inclusion-exclusion principle we get the number
$$7!-\binom51\times 6!+ \binom52\times 5!-\binom53\times 4!+ \binom54\times 3!-\binom55\times 2!=2428.$$
The answer is then $$\binom72\times2428=50988.$$
